How can I correctly get mongodb data at my deployed (by vercel) page?
When I try to get data use the fetchPrompts fuction, it works well at my localhost, but failed at my deployment (by vercel).
I try to get data every time I post/search one. However, no matter how many data I post, it only shows the data from the initial deployment, and never shows the data I post later. I am sure that mongodb has the data I post, and this problem only appears in the deployment environment, and it is normal in my localhost. Also, it is only a problem on this page, but other pages will successfully get all data, whether in the deployed environment or localhost.
'use client';

import { useState, useEffect, useMemo } from 'react';
import PromptCardList from '@components/PromptCardList';
import { useParams } from 'next/navigation';

const GetPrompts = () => {
  const params = decodeURIComponent(useParams().text.toString());
  const [prompts, setPrompts] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  console.log('params:', params);

  const fetchPrompts = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('/api/prompt');
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Failed to fetch prompts');
      }
      const data = await response.json();
      setPrompts(data);
      console.log('Prompts:', data);
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error.message);
      console.error('Failed to fetch prompts:', error);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPrompts();
  }, []);

  const filteredPrompts = useMemo(() => {
    if (params && params !== 'ALL') {
      const text = params.toLowerCase();
      return prompts.filter(
        (prompt) =>
          prompt.tag.toLowerCase().includes(text) ||
          prompt.prompt.toLowerCase().includes(text) ||
          prompt.creator.username.toLowerCase().includes(text),
      );
    }
    console.log('filteredPrompts:', prompts);
    return prompts;
  }, [params, prompts]);

  if (loading) {
    return (
      <section className="feed flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
        <div
          className="w-16 h-16 border-4 border-orange-500 border-t-transparent border-solid rounded-full animate-spin"/>
        <p className="mt-4 text-lg font-semibold text-gray-800">Loading
          prompts...</p>
      </section>
    );
  }

  if (error) {
    return (
      <section className={'feed'}>
        <p>Failed to load prompts</p>
      </section>
    );
  }

  return (
    <section className={'feed'}>
      <PromptCardList prompts={filteredPrompts}/>
    </section>
  );
};

export default GetPrompts;

UPDATE
I hardcode my fecth like this,
const response = await fetch('/api/users/66aa1b09cb219f41d09fa19c/prompts', {
        method: 'GET',
        cache: 'no-cache',
      });

it works well! so there must be something wrong with my fetch('/api/prompt'). Here are my api:
import { connectToDatabase } from '@utils/database';
import Prompt from '@models/prompt';

export const GET = async () => {
  try {
    await connectToDatabase();

    const prompts = await Prompt.find({}).populate('creator');
    return new Response(JSON.stringify(prompts), {
      status: 200,
      headers: { 'Cache-Control': 'no-store, max-age=0' },
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return new Response('Failed to fetch all prompts', { status: 500 });
  }
};

UPDATE 2
Source
Output
WHY my /api/prompt/route.js turn to a static file?

try adding "cache" : "no-store" in your fetch. check docs here

not work for me, i also try Purge Everything at my project setting, this time i get Failed to fetch prompts, only in this page too, others work well

export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'
ADD this in my /api/prompt/route.js

A good answer should always explain the solution. Maybe at least link to the documentation for this magic value:
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config#dynamic
